# How to change ISO in Nikon P900 for time lapse star trails?

Tags: nikon, astrophotography, nikon-p900

When I set up my P900 for time lapse star trails it shows the ISO as 100 in the bottom left of the monitor screen and no matter what I have tried, I cannot change the ISO to say, 1600 or 3200 for a shoot.
I have changed the ISO setting to 3200 in M P A S mode but when I go to time lapse star trails the ISO still shows as 100.
Is there a way to change the ISO setting?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exposure mode are you using when you "set up (your) P900 for time lapse star trails?"

Comment: I set up mode as follows - Scene --then Time-lapse movie -- then Star Trails (150 minutes). I must say also that I had set the ISO to 3200 in Star Trails the night before I wanted to take the movie and it remained as 3200 until I stupidly started to press buttons on the camera just before taking the movie when I noticed it was now ISO 100.

Comment: ISO 3200 on long exposure is not likely to yield a desirable result with a sensor that small.... the camera probably doesn't offer that for a reason.

Comment: You are correct regarding long exposures but the Star Trails exposure setting in the P900 is not a long exposure. It is an auto setting that opens the shutter for a 25 or 30 second exposure and then closes the shutter for some seconds before opening it again for 25 or 30 seconds. It does this for 150 minutes and then processes all the shots into a 10 second movie of star trails. Friends who also have this camera can set it for ISO 1600, 3200 and 6400 but I can't change mine from ISO 100.

Comment: 30 seconds is a long exposure.

Comment: 300 consecutive 30 second exposures heat up the sensor approximately the same as a single 150 minute exposure would. There's not that much cooling going on in the fraction of a second between each 30 second exposure.

Comment: @MichaelC this would still allow the camera to collect a thermally matched dark frame each time, though.

Comment: @rackandboneman Not without leaving a 30 second gap between each 30 second frame, which would kind of defeat the whole purpose of star trails. Not to mention: what good would a thermally matched dark frame do when the entire sensor would need to be masked because of the heat?

Comment: The Nikon P900 does not collect a dark frame at any time during the Time-lapse -- Star trail programme sequence. After exposure for 150 minutes the camera automatically processes all captured images into a 10 second video file.

Answer (score 3):

From [Nikon P900 field test](https://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/nikon-p900/nikon-p900-field-test.htm) imaging-resource.com:

> **High ISO Performance**
>
> [...] The camera's ISO sensitivity setting affects the camera's maximum exposure times. Only at ISO 100 can the camera shoot at its maximum shutter speed of 15”. At ISO 200, the maximum shutter speed is 8”. At ISO 400, the maximum shutter speed is 4”. At ISO 800, it's 2”. At ISO 1600, it's 1”. At ISO 3200 and 6400, it's ½”. Even in full manual mode, these limits remain. Unfortunately, this means that the P900 cannot be used for any night landscape work that doesn't feature a lot of artificial light.

It sounds like whatever you did after setting ISO 3200 in Star Trails mode set the shutter bulb to 8–15 seconds, which caused the camera to limit ISO to 100.

Comment: Thanks for your information - I think that is what I did do. It was dark, cold and I was flustered and pressed too many buttons.  Now to find a method of changing back from ISO 100.

Comment: All solved now - the ISO in Star trails is pre-set at 100 and it cannot be changed come hell or high water.  You can change the ISO in all modes except the pre-set ones which includes Time-lapse.  I was wrong and my friends were wrong.

Comment: Aso thanks guys for your comments and help. Until the next problem, see ya.